# Magento: Cannot send headers; headers already sent in controller?

Tags: magento

I searched the net but did not find anything that works in my case. I am getting the following error in /var/report when I click a button in my admin area.

```
a:5:{i:0;s:156:"Cannot send headers; headers already sent in /app/code/local/Whatever/Shipmentmails/controllers/SendController.php, line 1";i:1;s:1045:"#0 /lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php(115): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->canSendHeaders(true)
#1 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(1246): Zend_Controller_Response_Abstract->setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; char...')
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_App->getResponse()
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(202): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->getResponse()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#6 /app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#7 /index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#8 {main}";s:3:"url";s:75:"/index.php/shipmentmails/send/send/key/b5a96117c67af522e0df5f71ca31d1f8/";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:2:"de";}
```

It says its on line 1, but on line one I only have `<?php` and there is no space after it. I put a `Mage::log` in the function that is called by the button click but nothing is written to my log file (logging is enabled of course).

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

i have this problem and fixed adding `exit();` after `$this->getLayout()->getBlock(` in my case, in your case is when does `json_encode` or equivalent.

example:

```
echo json_encode($content);
exit;
```